# Simple Signal/emit to print message

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm trying to figure out how to use Signal to send custom messages/commands between widgets. I've been up and down all kinds of sources and I still can't figure it out.

The base purpose is that, I want to set a picture in GUI (custom button) that when I click on it, it changes the index number of a stacked widget. But to simplify, I figured click on image, it just prints a message, like 'hi' --> But even better would be if that message could be a predefined string (ala, the index number that I want to connect my image to)

I have so many setups but I'm going to try and write here what I think is my best.

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
import sys
from PIL import Image, ImageQt


def just_go():
    app.exit()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

screen = app.primaryScreen()
size = screen.size()
# <Code that sizes the window based on screensize>

program_window = window.size()
if program_window.width() > 200 and program_window.height() > 100:
    s_exit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(text="Quit", parent=window)
    s_exit.setGeometry(program_window.width() - 140, program_window.height() - 50, 120, 30)
    s_exit.clicked.connect(just_go)

image = ImageQt(Image.open('file'))
clicker = QLabel(window)
clicker.setPixmap(image)

b_buffer = QWidget(window)
foreground = QStackedLayout()
page_0 = QWidget()
page_1 = QWidget()
page_2 = QWidget()

foreground.addWidget(page_0)
foreground.addWidget(page_1)
foreground.addWidget(page_2)
b_buffer.setLayout(foreground)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and then:

```
def switch_tabs(page):
    foreground.setCurrentIndex(page)
```

Now I'm trying to make my project modular, so the actual file is in multiple python files but how would I make a Signal in one widget that emits to another? And then have a function run whenever that signal is sent?

Comment: There are some issues with both your question and your code. First of all, while a "procedural" approach can be used for very basic programs, due to the way [Py]Qt is structured, an object oriented paradigm is required. While in a code like the above you can use `switch_tabs` like that, you can't move that function in another file, as you will lose reference to `foreground`. In OOP, objects should act only on themselves (or their members). I strongly suggest you to do more research on the matter, as it's almost imperative for PyQt if you don't want to shoot on yourself in the foot every time.

Comment: Even assuming yours is a "pseudo-code": 1. widgets that have not been shown and *mapped* on the system (which happens only when the event loop is started) **always** have a predefined size: 640x480 for top level widgets, 100x30 for widgets created with a parent; that `if` block will never be executed; 2. even if it were, `just_go` is not defined, so you'll have an exception; 3. QMainWindow requires a *central widget*, and direct children are unsupported, so you need a basic container widget with a layout, use `setCentralWidget`, add a layout for that container and add all widgets to it;

Comment: 4. you're creating arbitrary widgets with the main window as parent (see above), with the result that they will all be overlapping and stacked one above the other; 5. `PIL.Image` is not a Qt QPixmap, you must use `ImageQt(image)`; you *must* use layout managers; 6. creating a QWidget and setting a QStackedLayout for it is pointless, just create a QStackedWidget;

Comment: Thank you for your response, sorry, I originally had "from PIL import ImageWorks # Not an actual module, just standin for code that already works" but then I thought I could just replace all the pseudo-code with 2 lines and figured, eh, might as well.

I made my actual code very modular, which is part of the reason I'm having issues because I want it to work across a whole range of circumstances. I just tried to file it down to the necessary code. I have setGeometry on most of my objects. But since I'm doing tons of trial and error, I have several projects and dozens of python files.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers, you make some good points and I'm going to change up my code likewise.

Comment: For future reference, please *always* take your time to create questions and their code, and if you do want to post pseudo-code, always specify it. Besides, even if it *is* pseudo-code, its logic and conceptual syntax must be respected anyway, otherwise it would just be confusing for us to understand what you're doing and if there are *actual* problems (we cannot understand if a problem is just in the pseudo-code or in the logic behind it). Good questions require *a lot* of time, even hours, but that time is always rewarded, usually with answers, or at least with upvotes or useful comments.

Comment: Note that in 99% of cases you don't need external modules to load images in Qt: one of the QPixmap constructors accepts a file path, so you can just do `image = QPixmap('path/to/image.png')`.